# python - readable list of objects

Tags: python, list

This is probably a kinda commonly asked question but I could do with help on this. I have a list of class objects and I'm trying to figure out how to make it print an item from that class but rather than desplaying in the;

```
<__main__.evolutions instance at 0x01B8EA08>
```

but instead to show a selected attribute of a chosen object of the class. Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to just display a particular attribute of each class instance, you can do

```
print([obj.attr for obj in my_list_of_objs])
```

Which will print out the `attr` attribute of each object in the list `my_list_of_objs`.  Alternatively, you can define the `__str__()` method for your class, which specifies how to convert your objects into strings:

```
class evolutions:
    def __str__(self):
        # return string representation of self

print(my_list_of_objs)  # each object is now printed out according to its __str__() method
```

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the __str__() and __repr__() methods.

See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to override your class's "to string" method:

```
class Foo:
    def __str__(self):
        return "String representation of me"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to override either the [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), or [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) methods of your object[s]

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to define a `__repr__` function that can reconstruct the object (whenever possible). Unless you have a `__str__` as well, both `repr()` and `str()` will call this method.

So for example

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Foo(%r, %r)' % (self.a, self.b)
```

Doing it this way, you have a readable string version, and as a bonus it can be eval'ed to get a copy of the original object.

```
x = Foo(5, 1 + 1)
y = eval(str(x))

print y
-> Foo(5, 2)
```